# Improve on timing of NMinimize

Tags: mathematical-optimization, performance-tuning

I got a little performance problem with the function NMinimize (it takes mathematica approximately 10 minutes to compute the results).

Here i s my sample code:

```
     (*Define variables*)
c = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
Subscript[f, k] = {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1};
L = {{1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}};
H = {{1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}};



y = Table[Unique["y"], {10}];
x = Table[Unique["x"], {38}];
variables = Join[y, x];

(*Define constraints*)
constraints1 = N[L].x == y;
constraints2 = N[H].x == N[Subscript[f, k]];
constraints3 = x >= 0;
constraints4 = y >= 0;

Print[constraints1]; Print[constraints2]; Print[constraints3]; \
Print[constraints4];

fun[y_, c_] := 
  Piecewise[{{y, 0 <= y/c <= 1/3}, {3 y - (2/3) c, 
     1/3 <= y/c <= 2/3}, {10 y - (16/3) c, 
     2/3 <= y/c <= 9/10}, {70 y - (178/3) c, 
     9/10 <= y/c <= 1}, {70 y - (178/3) c, 
     9/10 <= y/c <= 1}, {500 y - (1468/3) c, 
     1 <= y/c <= 11/10}, {5000 y - (16318/3) c, 
     11/10 <= y/c <= \[Infinity]}}];
NMinimize[{Sum[N[fun[y[[i]], N[c[[i]]]]/N[c[[i]]], 8], {i, 10}], 
   constraints1, constraints2, constraints3, constraints4}, variables,
   Method -> {"RandomSearch", 
    "InitialPoints" -> 
     Flatten[Table[{l, m}, {l, -2, 5, 0.00001}, {m, -2, 5, 0.00001}], 
      1]}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Are there maybe some options to increase the execution speed using "PrecisionGoal", "Accuracy Goal" or "WorkingPrecision". I was also thinking about using floating point numbers. In general, the solution to the problem is obtained with very high accuracy, which is not necessary in my case. So it would be nice if I could scarify some accuracy to get a better computation time.

Further, I know that the result will show the following error message, which is because of my strict constraints. What I don't understand is, why do I still get some results at the end if it violates these constraints? Is Mathematica then automatically switching to another approximation scheme?

```
NMinimize::incst: NMinimize was unable to generate any initial points satisfying the inequality constraints
```

Best,

Julian

Comment: `NMinimize` takes a `Method` option. in which you can specify a set of initial points. Take a look here for the different options you can use. http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html. For example, `Method -> {"RandomSearch", "InitialPoints" -> ... }`

Comment: I also suggest trying it with reals rather than integers. By converting all your variables using `N[]` I get a result, or rather the `NMinimize::incst` error you specify, in under 90 seconds, not 10 minutes.

Comment: how would you then set the InitialPoints? Could you maybe also post the changes that you have made so that I can test them on my machine?

Comment: Scroll down the tutorial to the Random Search method, and you'll find an example `NMinimize[f, {{x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50}}, 
 Method -> {"RandomSearch", 
   "InitialPoints" -> 
    Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, -45, 45, 5}, {j, -45, 45, 5}], 1]}]`

Comment: In terms of making it all numerics, just enclose all your variables in `N[]`, e.g. use `N[H]` instead of just `H`.

Comment: I just tried you suggestions, but they don't seem to speed up the process. I put all variables in N[] and tried to use Initial Points. However, I get the following error message: "Inappropriate parameter: \!\(\"InitialPoints\"\) -> "

Comment: You need to make sure the `InitialPoints` is appropriate to your case. Can you update your code to show how far you've got?

Comment: I just updated my code